# AssertionError's getMessage() curiously null

Tags: java, exception, assert

It's been ages since I engaged in single combat with a JVM, and I think I've forgotten something.

Got some code that has a ton of assertions, none with custom messages, just plain old `assert some_condition;`  I've verified that `-ea` is being passed to the VM, and double-checked programmatically at startup that assertions are in face enabled.

Higher up the call chain is code that looks like this:

```
try {
    start_the_deeply_nested_stuff();
}
catch (Throwable e) {
    do stuff with e.getMessage()
}
```

The docs for [AssertionError](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/AssertionError.html) say that it's descended from Throwable, and that it's always constructed with the asserted expression as the ctor argument (after being converted to a string).  I feel like I should be able to call getMessage() here and get something useful back, like *"assertion failed on file X line Y because your code sucks"*.

Instead, getMessage() returns null.  The only way I've been able to figure out that an assertion is being triggered at all is by looping over `e.getStackTrace()` and tracking down line numbers.

What's up with getMessage?  Isn't AssertionError always supposed to include something about the condition which triggered it?

Comment: Catching `Throwable` is probably a bad idea in general.

Comment: Because...?  Throwable is a parent class of both Exception and Error; this seems to be a great place to make use of that fact.  Do you have a reason for your assertion (no pun)?

Comment: Because the desire to catch all possible errors is a code smell in the first place.

Comment: The point here is to _log_ all possible errors, so forgive me if I disagree with your sweeping assertions.  :-)

Comment: Many errors should make your program actually crash, not just log an error message.  If you get an OutOfMemoryError, your program should crash all the way -- there is no recovering from such an error.  In general, `Exception`s are okay to catch, but `Error`s should result in a crash.

Comment: Many of our errors do in fact continue on to halt the program; they don't simply stop at logging.  "Crashing" without a log of what has happened is entirely unacceptable, so that's where this code comes into play.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Isn't AssertionError always supposed to include something about the condition which triggered it?

Apparently not - based on the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/assert.html).

The expression

```
assert args != null;
```

will throw an AssertionError with no detail message (if args is null)

```
assert args != null : "Arguments must not be null";
```

will throw an AssertionError with the detail message `Arguments must not be null`

I sympathize.  It would be really cool if the compiler was smart enough to take an expression like

```
assert args != null;
```

and throw an AssertionError with the message "args != null" but I guess that's not how it works.

I suppose you could write a script to go through all your old code, detect assert expressions and replace them with something like:

```
assert <expression> : "<text of expression>";
```

such as

```
assert args != null : "args != null";
```

Comment: Yar, that was it, thank you!  It's been too long since I had to deal with those.  I ran the files through a sed script (`s/assert \(.*\);/assert \1 : "assertion failed:  \1";/`) and everything is running as expected now!